# How to Add header row in text file using java

Tags: java, file-io

I have requirement to add header row in existing text file, is there any way to do it without affecting any other file format or structure.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/). Can you post it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6127648/writing-in-the-beginning-of-a-text-file-java

Answer (score 0):

Read the file, add the header and save the file:

```
try{
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(yourFile));
    String header = "Your Header";
    String content = "";
    while (in.ready()) {
      content += in.readLine();
    }
    in.close();

    String output = header + System.getProperty("line.separator") + content;

    FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(YourOutputFile);
    BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
    out.write(output);  
    out.close();

  }catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
```

Comment: I am using talend Open studio to automate some files using Dynamic schema load and it has constraint to each files must have header row.

Comment: i can not do replication of files to just add header row because i have files which big in size some of them are more than 50GB

Comment: You can write output to the same file, you can delete the old file if you want, but you should consider having a copy for any case which you optionally delete after checking that it works as you expect.

Comment: that solution I have with me, I just wanted to reduce time frame which we have to spend on recreate the file.

Comment: Thats exactly why you should have mentioned all this relelvant info in your question.

Comment: Any way there is no way to avoid reading and writing the file, not in java at least