# Add line at the beginning of text file - Java

Tags: java, file, file-io

I have a text file that says:

```
Joan
Paul
Carren
```

What I would like to do is add `Sean` at the top of the list in java

I have come across another question similar to this on stackoverflow, however, that answer overwrites the first name.

What i have right now is:

```
if (outputFile.exists()) {

            try {

                RandomAccessFile output = new RandomAccessFile(outputFileName, "rw");

                output.seek(0);
                output.write(headerComments.getBytes());

                output.close();

            } catch (IOException e) {

                System.out.println("IO Exception");

            }

        }
```

File image: http://postimg.org/image/pu043d0kv/

Answer (score 1):

Create a file `copy`. And supposed the original file is `original`.

- write the line `Sean` to file `copy`.
- for each line in file `original` copy to file `copy`
- delete the file `original`

Answer (score 0):

Similar question has been asked here [Java. How to append text to top of file.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16665124) but seem like not solved yet

You might want to try this:

```
BufferedReader read= new BufferedReader(new FileReader(yourfilename));
ArrayList list = new ArrayList();

String dataRow = read.readLine(); 
while (dataRow != null){
    list.add(dataRow);
    dataRow = read.readLine(); 
}

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(yourfilename); //same as your file name above so that it will replace it
writer.append(headerComments);

for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
    writer.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    writer.append(list.get(i));
}
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```