# add JSONOnject at the beginning of my old file JSON jackson java

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have already a json file, I don't want to create a new file. I need to add a jsonObject to this file using Jackson.
This is how I did, but here I am creating a new file !

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
File f = new File("/Users/sabrine/Documents/Workspace STS/Tache3.0/src/graph1.gjson");
mapper.writeValue(f, buildingGraph.graphMetadata);
```

How can I update my file with adding the object at the beginning of it?

Comment: Writing at the beginning of a file is usually not possible, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6127706/7677308

Comment: why can't you simply append the data from old file to this file at the end?

Comment: @Coder I was wondering if there is an other solution, but at the end this is wht I did