# Parse a file and modify content

Tags: java

I have a file which contains lines following the pattern `user:pass:role`. Right now I'm reading the whole line, then I parse the string with split, modify the values and create a new string, and finally write this new string to the file (deleting the old one).

Instead, I'm looking a way to read and write variable by variable. For example, the file content is:

```
jake:1234:developer
laura:qwerty:analyst
```

if I want to change Laura's role to dba, I want to do something like:

```
while file not empty do
    user = read file till ':'
    if user == "laura" then
        read file till next ':'
        modify "analyst" to "dba"
    else readline
```

How could I do this?

I have read this question about modifying a file [Modifying existing file content in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563294/modifying-existing-file-content-in-java), but the answer is to create a new file with the desired values and then delete the old file.

**edit**

all this arose because if I follow the method I have right now implemented, the new line end up appended to the file. So for instance, in the example above if I change Jake's role to dba, the file will be:

```
laura:qwerty:analyst
jake:1234:dba
```

Minor change but I rather keep the order.

Comment: And whats the Problem with creating a new file and delete the old one?

Comment: @markusw I rather don't do it this way.

Comment: You already did something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers that you have already read are coerent: in general, reading and writing the same file simultaneously is not a good idea.
The common way to do the job is to use a temp file.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by [RandomAccessFile](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) class but because **fields sizes is not fixed** it is will be hard and complex.