# How to update a commented out property in Java?

Tags: java, properties

My property file has properties like below:

```
#property1=
property2=asd
```

Is there a proper way to un comment and change the property1? I was looking at Apache Commons but there seems to be no non-ugly way to do this. The following wont work as the commented out property wont be read in the first place.

```
        PropertiesConfiguration config = new PropertiesConfiguration();
        PropertiesConfigurationLayout layout = new PropertiesConfigurationLayout(config);
        layout.load(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(filePath))));
        config.setProperty("#property1", "new_value");
        FileWriter propsFile = new FileWriter(filePath, false);
        layout.save(propsFile);
```

Comment: Yes. Open the file with your favorite text editor and delete the `#`. Don't forget to save the edited file.

Comment: How about using notepad?

Comment: At what time to you want to change this? During runtime? Why not just use an `if` case and a `boolean` instead?

Comment: You need to give some more information. Do you want to change the properties file programmaticly?

Comment: Yes, Programatically.

Comment: Updated the answer. If you cannot help please abstain from commenting things that are not helpful. I'm new to SO and I'm not just asking for answer without trying anything.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8563446/1679484

Comment: Try  `config.setProperty("property1", "new_value");`

Comment: That's adding it at the end of the file. That's not what I want though.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are looking for a way to do this in code, not with an editor.

If you read in the property file to java.util.Properties, the comments are all lost.

Your best bet is to read the property file into a String and update the string using a regex replace.

```
String newProperties = properties.replaceAll("^#*\s*property1=", "property1=");
Properties props = new Properties();
props.load(new StringReader(newProperties));
```

Comment: Comments are not lost if you use apache commons layout.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on what @garnulf said, you want to do `config.setProperty("property1", "new_value");`

You aren't "uncommenting" the property value, but rather adding the property to your configuration at runtime. The file will not be changed.

Your configuration will not include the commented out property when you first load it (because it is commented out). When you call `config.setProperty` it will be added to your config.

Comment: unfortunately I don't want this behavior. I just need to update the commented out property than add one at the end of the file

Comment: Are saying you want to write to your properties file programmatically? Do you want the properties to then take effect in your Java program?