# Java Caesar Cipher replacing a char in a string with an array value

Tags: java, arrays, string, encryption, char

Okay, so for a school project I am attempting to make a method that will take a file, use a caesar cipher to 'encrypt' it, and then output the new encrypted word to an output file, reading in all the words of the file to leave us with a separate encrypted file.

The problem I'm running into is I get a

> "Unexpected type. Required: variable. Found: value" error

whenever I try to replace the character with the new one.

Here's my encryption method, so hopefully that will be enough to find the problem.

```
public static void encrypt(File inputFile, int key) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    char[] alpha = new char[26];
    for(char ch = 'a'; ch <= 'z'; ch++)
    {
        int i = 0;
        alpha[i] = ch;
        i++;
    }
    Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFile);
    while(in.hasNext())
    {   
        String word = in.next();
        word = word.toLowerCase();
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < alpha.length; j++)
            {
                if(word.charAt(i) == alpha[j])
                {
                    word.charAt(i) = alpha[j + key];       
                }
            } 
        }

    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As Strings are immutable you can not do

```
word.charAt(i) = alpha[j + key];
```

Consider using a StringBuilder instead, like

```
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder ();
    for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < alpha.length; j++)
        {
            if(word.charAt(i) == alpha[j])
            {
                buf.append(alpha[j + key]);
            }
            else {
                buf.append (word[i]); // ??
            }
        }
    }

    // do something with buf ??
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have solved that problem. Just curious, how would you print this out to a file now? I need to print one word at a time obviously, but how would I go about doing that without overwritting the save file each time.

Comment: @Redfox2045 I am glad it helps.  Please consider to upvote and/or accept this answer.

Comment: @Redfox2045 As per your other question, please review http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563294/modifying-existing-file-content-in-java