# How to append existing line within a java text file

Tags: java, io

I'm having trouble adding to an exsisting line in a text file without overwriting that particular line or adding a new line.

for example, i have a line in my text file which is:

```
hello my name is
```

I would like to add to this line so it becomes:

```
hello my name is joe bloggs
```

Thanks

**i have a task to create a help desk program and i am trying to incorporate a feature that enables users to edit questions they have posted. as a result, the program will need to be able to append Any line within the text file - not necessarily just the last line**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822150/modify-a-txt-file-in-java

Comment: Read the entire I/O trail: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/ and specifically http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/rafs.html to learn I/O in Java.

Answer (score 3):

If it's not at the end of the file, you're in trouble - you're basically talking about *inserting* data in the middle of a file, which isn't traditionally supported by file systems.

The normal way to approach this is to create a *new* file - copy the portion before the insertion point from the old file, then write your new data, then copy the remainder of the original file afterwards. Finally, do whatever renaming/deleting you need.