# Restructure text file in java

Tags: java, text-files

I have text file content like

```
name1,name2,name3,....nameN
value1,value2,value3,....valueN
```

I want the content to be

```
name1     value1
name2     value2
name3     value3
  .        .
  .        .
nameN     valueN
```

How can I achieve this with java code.

Comment: You can write a code that does that.

Comment: See Peters answer for clues :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822150/modify-a-txt-file-in-java

Comment: I want the code. can you please refer me link/material where I can get the code? Am new to java.

Comment: `String#split` and `String#format` come to mind...

Comment: @MarounMaroun LOL!

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] names = namesString.split(',');
String[] values = valuesString.split(',');

//usage
System.out.println(names[0] + " with value " + values[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String[] names = namesString.split(",");
String[] values = valuesString.split(",");

for(int i=0;i<names.length;i++){
System.out.println(names[i] + "      " + values[i];
}
```

Comment: So what is namesString here, Is that contain first line of text file, If so it is giving me error

Comment: `String[] names = namesString.split(",");` double quote is working for me

Comment: Thanks, that will be double quote.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
            File file = new File("D:\\temp\\test.txt");
            InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
            String namesString = bufferedReader.readLine();
            String valuesString = bufferedReader.readLine();
            String[] names = namesString.split(",");
            String[] values = valuesString.split(",");
            for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(names[i] + "\t" + values[i]);
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```